# Solving Homophone Confusion

Tags: nlp, nltk, text-processing, stanford-nlp

This may be a question that is not suitable for stackoverflow, but I had no other better place to ask it. I was wondering if there are any known tools (non-commercial) that can be used to solve the homophone confusions such as these in a sentence?

- it's vs its
- you're vs your

I am new to NLP and I haven't used any of the known tools. Tried to search for these in google but nothing useful shows up. Are there any parts in NLTK or CoreNLP that cover this?

Comment: hi! what do you mean when you say "solve the homophone confusions"? do you want to automatically correct these occurrences when you have typed input?

Comment: Yes indeed! In the normal spoken text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with this topic but I found a how to PDF that may be of some use to you.

[How to solve homophone problems](http://csl.ira.uka.de/fileadmin/Vorlesungen/WS2010-11/ATSP/presentations/IvayloJanev_HomophonesInASR.pdf)

Comment: Sounds like we have to train it ourselves. Here I could find a good training data. http://conc.lextutor.ca/concordancers/

Answer (score 1):

It's no complete solution, but [LanguageTool](https://www.languagetool.org) has some rules for this. See the [rule file](https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/blob/master/languagetool-language-modules/en/src/main/resources/org/languagetool/rules/en/grammar.xml) and search for `rulegroup id="IT_IS"`(disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of LanguageTool). [After the Deadline](http://afterthedeadline.com/) also uses a rule-based approach, only that it tries to avoid useless suggestions by filtering its suggestion against a large n-gram database.

Comment: Thanks. Sound like a strange way of doing it, since classifiers are being used rather than rule-based systems. N-grams are more useful in this context I guess. And a gigantic train set!